# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7, trying to get a local server version of Plaid running to pull my bank account balance into my bills spreadsheet. I keep running up against a `UnicodeDecodeError` and I can't figure it out.

I've tried to isolate which lines were the problem and fixing them with a Unicode identifier. I've gotten Syntax errors on the `PLAID_ENV`, `PLAID_PRODUCTS`, and python lines when running in debug mode. I've tried running `server.py` without python in front of it.

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID='5bf874c39bb5dc0012b1be13' \
PLAID_SECRET='*Redacted because secret*' \
PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY='8a2fc8ffb6c20e69159eded19cf77f' \
PLAID_ENV=‘development’ \
PLAID_PRODUCTS=‘balance’ \
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES='US,CA,GB,FR,ES' \
python server.py
```

This is the output I get when trying to navigate to 127.0.0.1:5000 :

```
[2019-10-01 10:54:57,573] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "server.py", line 43, in index
plaid_country_codes=PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
ctx.app,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/siekmang/quickstart/python/templates/index.ejs", line 244, in top-level template code
countryCodes: '{{ plaid_country_codes }}'.split(','),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the delimiters around the `PLAID_ENV` and `PLAID_PRODUCTS` values aren't ASCII `'` single quotes, they're `‘` and `’`.

Comment: @martineau well spotted :)

Comment: @martineau Thank you! I knew I just needed a new set of eyes on it!